# Describe transition of a class in UML's Statechart Diagram

Tags: class, oop, uml, statechart

I read that Statechart Diagram is generally used to describe transition of an object. One of those objects is a class.

Could you give me an instance of how to generate statechart diagram showing transition of a class in OOP programming?

I've googled it before, but found nothing.
The part where I'm a bit confused is where to put functions and attributes of a class in statechart diagram.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Attributes/operations are part of the transitions. You can check attributes as part of a Guard which limits transition between states. On Entry/Exit (and inside) of a state you can perform operations of the class.

Edit based on your comment:

Suppose I have a class called `Teacher` with two functions named `getteachername()` and `setteachername()` with one attribute named `name`.

You would use a state chart (in the following very trivial and silly case) if you need to implement constraints. Say that the name can only be set on a rule that allows to append a string to it if it starts with "Paul". Then you start with the state `isEmpty`. It has an outgoing transition `modify` where it goes to `statePaul` if the name is set to "Paul". From that state you can transit to the same state when appending something to `name`. From the `stateOther` you can only transit to the `isEmpty`.

Note that this is constructed, silly and non-realistic. But it shows how a state machine controls changes of attributes based on using methods of a class.

Comment: Yes, as in UML State Machine Diagram Example [uml-diagrams.org: DICOM Hosted Application Life Cycle](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dicom-hosted-application-uml-state-machine-diagram-example.html?context=stm-examples) and it's example neighborhood

Comment: I'm still confused on defining things to be in a statechart diagram. Suppose I have a class called "teacher" with two functions named "getteachername()" and "setteachername()" with one attribute named "name". So how can I generate statechart diagram based on that class?